# Принцип защиты внутренних данных класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Имея интерфейс модуля подумал что стоило бы закрыть от внешнего доступа внутреннее поле, т.е. сделать подобное:

```
class A
{
// Если будет проблема с оффсетами то думаю последовательное объявление
// хоть как-то поможет
public:
    virtual void some_public_method();
    ...
private:
    void* some_private_data;
    ...
};
```

Но отдать папку `include` с заголовками такого вида:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void some_public_method();
...
};
```

Но, при отдаче заголовков удалить все приватные поля, т.е. оставить только публичные методы. Хотелось бы узнать не повлияет ли такое решение на работоспособность класса при работе с внутренними полями?

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясен, но, кажется, вам нужен pimpl

Comment: Мне кажется, что так делать нельзя.

Comment: @alexolut, он хочет в h-файле оставить только описание публичной части, а приватная, соответственно, будет только в c-реализации.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, именно так хочу сделать

Comment: Так определяете интерфейс (т.е. класс со всеми виртуальными методами) отдельно. А класс реализации (с приватными полями), реализующий этот интерфейс наружу не выставляете.

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что всегда можно будет прочитать (и зачастую записать) данные напрямую по адресу в памяти независимо от заголовков

Comment: @andreymal что в большинстве случаев вызовет неопределённое поведение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На языке стандарта C++ это называется нарушением Правила Одного Определения (ODR violation). Поскольку в одной программе имеется два разных определения одного класса.

Если говорить точнее, то стандарт разрешает иметь больше одного определения если они эквивалентны. Что означает что разные определения должны состоять из одинаковой последовательности токенов.

Параграф 3.2 стандарта C++:

> 6 There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9)...
> Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> — each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens;...

Нарушением этого правила будет неопределённое поведение:

> If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

---

Вариантом решения проблемы в данном случае будет, например, применение идиомы PIMPL, как уже было сказано, либо использование чисто виртуального интерфейса в качестве базового класса.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что так делать нельзя, поскольку компилятор при неправильном объявлении класса может обращаться к полям по неправильным смещениям.

Comment: А если пометить методы виртуальными для генерации `vtable`, это не исправит такую проблему?

Answer (score 1):

`void*` неудачно, изучайте PIMPL https://habr.com/post/111602/  хорошо написано также в "сложных задачах" (Герб Саттер).

Comment: Эм.. А как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Не понимаю причем тут `PIMPL`...

Answer (score 1):

PIMPL = указатель на реализацию . Новый класс создаётся с указателем на секретный объект. Выкладывается только **hpp** этого класса , в котором в основном прописаны публичные методы секретного объекта. А заголовок секретного объекта как-бы забывают выложить. В основном эта идея была для реализации библиотек. Минус в скорости.
Public.hpp:

```
class Secret;
class Public{
public:
  Public();
  ~Public();
  void PublicMethod();
private:
  Secret * s ; 
};
```

Public.cpp:

```
Public::Public():s(new Secret){}
Public::~Public(){delete s;}
void Public::PublicMethod(){s->PublicMethod();}
```

Secret.hpp:

```
class Secret{
public:
  Secret();
  void PublicMethod();
private:
  void PrivateMethod();
};
```

Ещё один вариант ограничивать доступ к приватным полям это создать два класса приватный и публичный. Все загружают прямо публичный класс, и автоматом загружается реализация приватная.

```
// private.hpp
class Private {
protected:
  int privatex;
  int PrivateF();
};

// private.cpp
# include "public.hpp"
int Private::PrivateF(){return privatex+((Public*)this)->publicx;}


// public.hpp
# include "private.hpp"
class Public : public Private {
public :
  int publicx ;
  int PublicF();
};

// public.cpp
# include "public.hpp"
int Public::PublicF(){return privatex + PrivateF();}

// main.cpp
# include "public.hpp"
int main(){
  Public x;
  // x.privatex ; // нет доступа
  // x.PrivateF();  // нет доступа
  x.PublicF(); // ok
  x.publicx = 0; // ok
}

//> g++ -c main.cpp public.cpp private.cpp 
//> g++ main.o private.o public.o
```

Этот вариант НЕ даёт увеличение скорости компиляции. Только скрывает скромно реализацию.

Comment: Можно класс разделить на две части : приватный и публичный. Они в разных файлах и никого не нагружают. Посмотрите в моём ответе.